# Custom Autogenerated Column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to generate a unique `PrescriptionNo` for each of the `Prescription` based on the `shopid`.

I have tried the following way

```
id   PrescriptionNo   Shopid  Amount 
1    PRES001             2     100
2    PRES002             2     200
3    PRES001             1     100
4    PRES003             2     200
```

```
select top 1 'PRES' + right('000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) + 1 AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
  from prescription
 where shopid = 2
 order by id desc
```

Comment: Hi  Dale , Problem with above is that  if there is no previous record based on shop I want to set PRES001 as  PrescriptionNo

Comment: Do what you are currently doing, except store the number in a separate column to avoid the nasty string calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #tmp1 (id int, prescriptionno varchar(10), shopid int, amount int);
insert into #tmp1 values (1,'PRES001',2,100);
insert into #tmp1 values (2,'PRES002',2,200);
insert into #tmp1 values (3,'PRES001',1,100);
insert into #tmp1 values (4,'PRES003',2,200);

select 'PRES' + RIGHT(concat('000',ISNULL(max(right(prescriptionNo,3)),0)+1),3)
from #tmp1
where shopid = 3

=> Returns 'PRES0001'

select 'PRES' + RIGHT(concat('000',ISNULL(max(right(prescriptionNo,3)),0)+1),3)
from #tmp1
where shopid = 2

==> Returns 'PRES0004'
```

By using just max() allows you to use ISNULL(..,0).